# Including jquery4php in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

How can I include jquery4php(http://jquery4php.sourceforge.net/) in yii? I have added following lines in my layout/main.php

```
<?php
Yii::import('application.extensions.lib.*');
require_once('YepSua/Labs/RIA/jQuery4PHP/YsJQueryAutoloader.php');
YsJQueryAutoloader::register();
?>
```

But when I use

```
<?php
echo 
YsJQuery::newInstance()
  ->onClick()
  ->in('#buttonId')
  ->execute('alert("Hello World")')
?>
```

in some other file yii shows

> include(YsJQuery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

error. So How can I include jquery4php in yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include jquery in yii it is already done. All you have to do to include the lib is:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('jquery');
```

If you use jQuery4php you will loose the ability to place your script where you want and create an abstraction where it's unneeded.

But if you decide to use it. Put your register script in index.php or in controller.
layout/main is the last thing that is renderer in yii and there for the lib isn't loaded when you call your api

Hope this helps

Claude